# European bus tour companies for middle age people?

Tags: europe, buses, tours

I'm looking to do a tour of Europe for 15 days this September  with my mum.  I am 34 and she is 65.
The package tour companies I've looked at like Trafalgar,  contiki and top deck, cater mainly for young 20 somethings or elderly 50 plus.

Are there any companies suitable for my mum and I?  I.e not too old, not too young?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the "old folks" tours also have middle aged adults participating.  While they target the older working folks and retired crowd in their advertising because they have the time and money to travel, you often see adult children accompanying their parents or middle aged couples or singles.

There are no guarantees you will find a same aged person on your trip, but likely there will some nearer to your age.

Actually come fall you may even see grey hairs in the Contiki tours ;-)